# How to create parent pom.xml in a multi-module Maven archetype from template?

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I created a multi-module Maven archetype following http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/examples/create-multi-module-project.html with the following parent  `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>${rootArtifactId}</artifactId>
  <version>${version}</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>${rootArtifactId}</name>
  <modules>
    <module>${rootArtifactId}-jar</module>
    <module>${rootArtifactId}-ejb</module>
    <module>${rootArtifactId}-web</module>
    <module>${rootArtifactId}-ear</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

in `src/main/resources/archetype-resources/pom.xml`. I expect the resulting `pom.xml` after `mvn archetype:generate` to include the `modules`  element and it's children with `rootArtifactId` replaced, however the resulting `pom.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>myArtifact</name>
</project>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you put the `archetype-resource` module inside `src/main/resource`?

Comment: @araknoid I followed https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html. That's the only reason. Is that wrong or troublesome? Are there alternatives?